# Tried to move mails from Inbox to PST, but they vanished

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, pst

I have written a simple script with the aim to backup Inbox, Archived and Sent mails to an attached PST datafile.

It seems it works fine: the script found source folders from my email account, it found destination folders on the attached PST, it found the mails to be backupped (ie I have deeply checked out the `$namespace` object).

When I have reopened my Outlook client I got an unpleasant surprise. As expected, my mails aren't stored in my email account, **but none of them appear in my attached PST**.

*What's happened???*

Edit: alternatively, could you suggest to me any dcumentation about Outlook MAPI for Powershell? Google returns to me weak results

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$SourceDest = [ordered]@{}
$SourceDest['Inbox'] = 'PSTfolder1'
$SourceDest['Archive'] = 'PSTfolder2'
$SourceDest['Sent'] = 'PSTfolder3'

foreach ($from_folder in $SourceDest.Keys) {
    $to_folder = $SourceDest[$from_folder]
    $Source = $namespace.Folders['mymail@account.com'].Folders[$from_folder]
    $Dest = $namespace.Folders['myPST'].Folders[$to_folder]
    $Messages = $Source.Items
    foreach ($msg in $Messages) {
        [void]$msg.Move($Dest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Some additional info for my individual case study:

1. The email account is a Office365 account and it belongs to my firm.
2. The PST file, instead, is local and I am using it for backup purpose
3. The script works fine and it doesn't return any error, may I debug it with some breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Was Outlook running at the time the script was executed? Do you see emails being moved?

Keep in mind that `Move` is a function that returns the new item, it does not return void. Not that it should matter in your case.

What does matter is that you are modifying the collection (since `Move` deletes the original) as you are looping through its items. Use a back loop from `Items.Count` down to 1.

Comment: Outlook client must be closed before running the script, otherwise an error message arise (I found that this is due to running Outlook elevated through the script, during the object creation). If I well understood the Move method returns the mails selected, then I have to collect and redirect mails to target destination folder. Is it correct? How can I accomplish such task?

Comment: Why is your script running with elevated privileges? As for Move, there is no reason to "redirect" anything - Move returns the new object in case your need to do something with the newly created item in the target folder. Or you can just ignore the return value